# Why does this ajax request have a data string with a bunch of numbers with dashes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, encoding

I'm looking at a website with javascript games and I'm seeing how it saves high scores.
The code looks like this:

```
    (new Request({
        url: window.location.toString().split("#")[0],
        data: {
            action: "save_score",
            score: this.tenths,
            time_started: SERVER_TIME
        },
        onSuccess: HighScores.updateAndShow.bind(HighScores)
    })).send()
```

But when I beat the game and save my high score I look in Chrome developer tools, the request looks like this

```
    Form Data
    action:save_score
    data:115-100-113-115-103-66-49-58-56-63-38-117-126-108-120-118-120-122-116-112-128-112-107-116-116-125-84-72-69-71-53-126-121-120-117-104-104-62-145-90-81-110-133-83-83-145-132-97-93-149-135-139-105-76-107-77-117-132-96-136-105-123-136-87-63-125-95-61-59-77-61-59-59-69-51-114-57-143-148-160-196-115-193-188-188-172-192-186-174-185-185-138-125-115-193-182-186-178-172-192-193-174-191-193-178-177-138-126-128-132-129-133-132-133-133-134-132
```

I can't figure out how "score: this.tenths, time_started: SERVER_TIME" is being converted to "data:115-..." I can't find anywhere in the javascript where this string is being created.

Is this a standard way of encoding? Is this something automatically converted by the browser? Does this look like a common ajax library that creates this string of numbers with dashes? Do you think this is for security or it just needs to send all those numbers and they decided they would just separate each one with a dash? Is the Request class a common thing or something they coded?

I'm going to code high scores for my own game and I want it to be safe from hacking somehow.

Comment: which library are you using? Your code is most definitely not vanilla javascript, so anything could be happending here.

Comment: The code is probably minified, so trying to figure it out in the debugger will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything could be going on here. Maybe the numbers are character codes?

If you want to secure your game against cheaters you can log all the actions the user takes and recreate the game session on the server and calculate the high score there. But then of course you'll still run into problems with people using bots.

Comment: I tried decoding it as ASCII codes, didn't get anything intelligible.

Comment: Maybe this is creating it: function obfuscate(a, b) {
    for (var c = "", d = 0, e = a.length; d < e; d++) c += "-" + (a.charCodeAt(d) + b % (d + 1));
    return c.substr(1)
}

Comment: "score" 115 = s, 100 = c+1, 113=o+2, 115 = r+1, 103 = e+2

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the `Request` object is a custom class in that site's library and, if that's the case, probably has its own data serializing algorithms set up to transfer data in a specific way.